# Conversión de fecha

Tags: c#

Tengo este formato de fecha:

```
Thu Apr 18, 2019  12:44 pm
```

Estoy leyendo esta informacion de un archivo...
Cuando encuentra la primera palabra en este caso Thu, entra al `if`, y empiezo la recolección de información al final tengo una variable `tacTime` donde junto las variables quedando como resultado

```
18 Apr 2019
```

--
Hay algun tipo de conversión que al final obtenga la fecha de esta manera:

```
04/18/2018 (mes/dia/año)
```

--

```
if (arreglo[0] == "Thu")
    {

    string m = arreglo[1].Substring(0, 3);
    string month = m;

    string d = arreglo[2].Substring(0, 2);
    string day = d;

    string y = arreglo[3].Substring(0, 4);
    string year = y;

    tacTime = day + " " + month + " " + year;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo aplicando el formato directo con la función `toString`

Ejemplo:

```
string dateInput="Thu Apr 18, 2019  12:44 pm";
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(dateInput);
var fechaCorta = fecha.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

otra opción seria

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("Thu Apr 18, 2019  12:44 pm", new CultureInfo("de-DE"),DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, como bien te ha puesto Juan Carlos en su respuesta, puedes usar simplemente `DateTime.Parse` para parsear tu cadena de fecha a un DateTime.

Yo añado otra opción en la que puedes definir exactamente el formato de tu cadena de fecha para parsearlo a `DateTime` en el caso de que `Parse` no detecte correctamente la fecha de la cadena.

Para ello, debes usar [DateTime.ParseExact](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) o bien [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) 
 usando los formatos de fecha explicados en [Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

En tu caso, sería algo asi:

```
string dateInput="Thu Apr 18, 2019  12:44 pm";
DateTime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(fechaaaaa, "ddd MMM dd, yyyy  hh:mm tt", new CultureInfo("en-EN"));
```

Y posteriormente, si quieres una cadena con otro formato, como bien te comentan en la otra respuesta, puedes usar `ToString` con una cadena personalizada:

```
var fechaCorta = fecha.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```